# Is there something omitted around or in the phrase?

Tags: meaning

> No, Bessie: she came to my crib last night when you were gone down to supper, and said I need not disturb her in the morning, or my cousins either; and she told me to remember that she had always been my best friend, and **to speak of her and be grateful to her accordingly**.
>   (Jane Eyre)

I can't understand the highlighted part. Is there something omitted around, or in the phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three omitted words are "**she told me** to speak of her and be grateful...".

Comment: Yes, I know that. But what does 'speak of her' mean? I mean, speak of her what? Is it an idiom?

Comment: @Listenever It's not an idiom.  I think it means to speak of her *accordingly*, that is, to keep in mind that they had always been best friends when she chooses her words.

Comment: @Listenever: To "speak of" someone is to talk about them when they aren't there. There's an idiom about talking about people "behind their back"; that's generally called "gossip" & it's usually private & personal information that shouldn't be shared with others, & it's often untrue. Here's a link to a relevant 1930s song: [_Please Don't Talk About Me When I'm Gone_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Please_Don't_Talk_About_Me_When_I'm_Gone).

Comment: **she told me** already appears earlier in the sentence, and there is no need to repeat it -- it is implied for the final (highlighted) phrase. She's asking the narrator to, as a friend, always speak well of her and to remember that friendship and feel grateful towards her.